# IndexError: "pop index out of range" with a for loop

Tags: python

How can I resolve this `IndexError`? I tried by using a `while` loop, but nothing changed.

Here is my code, it should check the length of the object of two lists (`la`, `lb`) and remove the string from `la` if the string is shorter than the `lb` string and vice versa. Plus it has to remove both of the strings if their length is the same.

```
def change(l1, l2):
    la1 = l1[:]
    la2 = l2[:]
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(la1)): 
        if la1[i] == la2[i]:
            l1.pop(i)
            l2.pop(i)
        elif la1[i] > la2[i]:
            l2.pop(i)
        elif la2[i] > la1[i]:
            l1.pop(i)
```

Comment: `list.pop` will raise `IndexError` if the list is empty.

Comment: You are not comparing string lengths but just strings.

Comment: Do you have a (short) usage example?

Comment: The next indexes change once you have removed an element.

Comment: Are lists la1 and la2 of the same size?

Comment: Could you check if my answer solves your problem, and - if so - mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 5):

**Assuming your lists are of equal lengths**

As has been pointed out in the comments, the `IndexError` happens due to your lists' length changing when you `pop()` an item.

Since you're iterating over your list using a `range(len(l))` in a `for` loop, which isn't updated after every completed loop, you'll eventually hit an index that's out of range.

An example, which you can try easily enough yourself:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for i in range(len(l)):
    l.pop(i)
    print("Length of list", len(l))
```

Do not confuse yourself by calling `print(range(len(l))` in the for loop - this will give you an updated range, but is misleading. The `range` in the for loop is only called once, hence never updates while iterating.

**A different approach**

Instead of working with indices, try using `zip()` and building new lists, instead of changing existing ones.

```
def change(l1, l2):
    new_l1 = []
    new_l2 = []
    for a, b in zip(l1, l2):
        if len(a) == len(b):
            continue # do nothing
        elif len(a)<len(b):
            new_l2.append(b)
        elif len(a)>len(b):
            new_l1.append(a)
    return new_l1, new_l2
```

This approach, essentially, generates the same list you create using `pop()`, while avoiding usage of indices.

Note that `zip()` will stop once it reaches the end of the smaller of both iterables. If your lists may not be of equal length, and you'd like to iterate until the longest of both iterables is iterated over entirely, use `zip_longest()`. But I do not think this is what you need in this case.

**Additional Notes**

You would also run into a problem if you were to iterate over your `list` using the following code:

```
l = [i for i in range(10)]
for item in l:
    l.remove(item)
>>>[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Essentially, it's ***not advisable to iterate over any `iterable` while changing it***. This can result in anything from an `Exception` being thrown, to silent unexpected behaviour.

I'm aware you were avoiding this by looping over the copies, I just wanted to add this for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the lists backwards, so that when you remove an item from the list the indices of the elements that you have not examined yet won't be affected

```
def f(a, b):
    l = len(a) if len(a)<len(b) else len(b)
    for i in range(l):
        j = l-i-1
        la, lb = len(a[j]), len(b[j])
        if la<lb: a.pop(j)
        elif lb<la: b.pop(j)
        else: a.pop(j), b.pop(j)
    return a, b
```

ps I staid faithful to your problem statement and not to your implementation re the comparison based on strings' lengths.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to iterate over a list and want to empty it
but don't want pop index error use this:

```
lst = [ 1, 4, 56, 2, 4 , 12,  6, 89 ,11, 0]
i =0
while len(lst) != 0:
    lst.pop(0)
    i+=1
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pop throw the `IndexError` also if you specify an index to it, and the list is smaller than your index:

```py
>>> [100].pop(1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: pop index out of range
```