# pop index out of range: For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop

**Final Answer**

I was able to make it work using for loop:
problem lied in pop(i) range. It just needed to be
one less, since it starts at 0.

```
for i in range(0,len(list_ex1)):
    value=list_ex1.pop((len(list_ex1)-1))
    list_ex2.append(value)
```

**Question**

```
list_ex1 = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 111, 222, 333, 'Hello World']
list_ex2 = []

for i in range(len(list_ex1)):
    value = list_ex1.pop(i)
    list_ex2.append(value)
```

> pop index out of range

```
>>> print(list_ex1)
['bbb', 111, 333]
>>> print(list_ex2)
['aaa', 'ccc', 222, 'Hello World']
```

I do not understand how can I pop all the values from `list_ex1` using a `for` loop.

**old update**

This code works by taking the last value from the list.

```
i = 0
while len(list_ex1) != 0:
    value = list_ex1.pop(len(list_ex1)-1)
    list_ex2.append(value)
    i+=1
```

Comment: the last code in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40130482/indexerror-pop-index-out-of-range-with-a-for-loop) worked ,thanks. But what is the enumerate method somebody mentioned?

Comment: You can look it up in the Python documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iterator variable in your loop is going to go out of range because you are modifying the length of the list, therefore it cannot be used to access the list.
Instead of doing:

```
value = list_ex1.pop(i)
```

Do:

```
value = list_ex1.pop(0)
```

This will only pop the front item, once that front item is popped the next item becomes the new item at index 0, do this for the length of the list and each item in the list will be popped off.